# Is there a way to configure android app to receive activity result between onStart and onStop?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, android-lifecycle, onactivityresult

I see very odd sequence of events when compared to [Android lifecycle overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). My app calls other activity (file selector) and waits for the result. Such events happen:

- my app calls StartActivityForResult (file selector shows up)
- OnStop is called
- OnActivityResult is called
- OnStart is called

The last two events looks like mixed order to me, because technically my app works (code inside OnActivityResult) while being stopped. It even sounds weird :-).

Did I do something wrong? Is there a way to configure my app/activity for "correct" order -- i.e. first being woke up and then get OnActivityResult?

*Gingerbread 2.3 if this matters.*

Comment: Ok,i post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is correct.When `OnStop` is called,you will on the second activiy.At this time,`OnActivityResult` is not called,it was a callback when you do something like `SetResult` and finish the second activity,then the first activity will handle `OnStart` method.